# After session expires redirect to login page in yii

Tags: session, redirect, authentication

I am developing an web application which has several levels and modules. In application everything working fine.

If users are not working after logging they leave the application in login state and try to use it after 1 hour then session expires and system sate variables are lost. So in this case application not redirecting to login page (site/login) which is bad user experience.

I am not able to identify what the problem is. How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

A way of solving this would be to have your controllers not extend from CController directly.

You could have an intermediate controller say ModuleController that extends CController. 
Then all your controllers extend that controller.

Override beforeAction() in ModuleController and check whether sessions are set and redirect to login if not. 
So every time a user tries to access a page it will first check for whether the session is set. You could use ACL to fine tune this better.

This method could be applied to a variety of issues in Yii development.

Hope this helps!